# JSON schema validate oneOf with condition

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

How can I set json schema validator for next objects?
They all have field `account_id`, but `options` is dependent on `type`.

In case of `twitter` it has list of `tokens`, each of those has four fields. 
If `type` is `instagram`, than each token has only one field in 
`tokens`.
And for `facebook` `type` field `options` must be empty.

```js
{
  "type": "twitter",
  "account_id": "xyz",
  "options": {
    "tokens": [{
      "access_token": "long string",
      "access_token_secret": "long string",
      "consumer_key": "long string",
      "consumer_secret": "long string"
    }]
  }
}

{
  "type": "instagram",
  "account_id": "xyz",
  "options": {
    "tokens": [{
      "access_token": "long string"
    }]
  }
}

{
  "type": "facebook",
  "account_id": "xyz",
  "options": {}
}
```

Is it possible to make json schema, that would satisfy those requirements? Even the most simple schema when definition for every `type` is wrapped in `oneOf` keywords does not work.

```js
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "oneOf": [{
      "properties": {
        "account_id": {
          "type": "string",
        },
        "type": {
          "const": "facebook"
        },
        "options": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "account_id",
        "type",
        "options"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "account_id": {
          "type": "string",
        },
        "type": {
          "const": "twitter"
        },
        "options": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
              "access_token": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "access_token_secret": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "consumer_key": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "consumer_secret": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "access_token",
              "access_token_secret",
              "consumer_key",
              "consumer_secret"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "account_id",
        "type",
        "options"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "account_id": {
          "type": "string",
        },
        "type": {
          "const": "instagram"
        },
        "options": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
              "access_token": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "access_token"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "account_id",
        "type",
        "options"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: You have the right idea.  Here are a couple hints.  (1) Remove all `additionalProperties` keywords.  This keyword wreaks havoc when combining schemas.  You can add them back in where you can when you have everything else working.  (2) Your "options" schema should be an object with a "tokens" property.  The "tokens" schema is what should be an array.  Good luck.

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers thank you for your help. Sorry for the late reply ;)